# How to change the default "User" participant label in ZenUML sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I want to use the User stick-man, but with a different name, other than the default "User".

If I use `@Starter(User)` the stick-man shows up, but if I use `@Starter(Buyer)`, the stick-man disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [ZenUML Web App](https://zenuml.com) and the [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-sequence/kcpganeflmhffnlofpdmcjklmdpbbmef) support custom CSS. Put the following CSS in the CSS tab will solve your problem:

```
.lifeline.starter .participant:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 45px;
  width: 88px;
  background-size: 80px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='166' height='116'%3E%3Cg fill='none' stroke='%23000'%3E%3Cpath d='M91.166 19.72a13.195 13.069 0 11-26.39 0 13.195 13.069 0 1126.39 0z' transform='matrix(1.1316 0 0 1.14252 -5.728 4.262)'/%3E%3Cpath d='M82.498 42.266v46.057m0-.569l-19.446 16.542M82.53 87.754l21.34 15.468m-41.795-48.36l41.858-.032'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.lifeline.starter .participant {
  border: none;
}
```

[image]